# How to wrap text inside a div while div stays in the same place?

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

I have made a simple version of my code:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
  float: left;
  color: #0000FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.second {
  float: left;
  color: #0000FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="box first">Username</div>
  <div class="box second">This is a short message</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="box first">Username</div>
  <div class="box second">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="box first">Username</div>
  <div class="box second">Message</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the second group of `divs` contains a lot of text.

I want the second `div` to stay fixed next to the first div and the text inside the second `div` should wrap on multiple lines. (like it does already)

I use bootstrap, so I don't want to use a fixed width. Is it only possible adding a width?

Comment: Set a width for `.first` and `.second`. Also why not just use a table for what you are doing there? Looks pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1

This can't be done in the current structure without setting a width. However, you might be able to do this by setting just 1 width.

If you give the `.first` a set width, absolutely position, and set `.second` with a padding to fit the `.first`-div, you might solve this, while keeping `.second` fluid.

```css
    .box {
     border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .row {
        position: relative;
    }
    .first {
     position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
     color: #0000FF;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0 20px;
        width: 80px;
    }
    .second {
     box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
     color: #0000FF;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0 20px 0 140px;
    }
    .clear{
     clear: both;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">Username</div>
    <div class="box second">This is a short message</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">Username</div>
    <div class="box second">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">Username</div>
    <div class="box second">Message</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Downsides to this method are that `.first` is still a solid width, and this doesn't work in older browsers, as `box-sizing` doesn't get support in older browsers.

## Option 2

An alternative is using a table instead of divs. That would give you the following code:

```css
    .box {
     border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .first {
     color: #0000FF;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .second {
     color: #0000FF;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="box first">Username</td>
    <td class="box second">This is a short message</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="box first">Username</td>
    <td class="box second">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="box first">Username</td>
    <td class="box second">Message</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Upside to this method is: It's broadly supported.
Downside: It's a table . . .

Comment: Upside to this method is: It's broadly supported. Downside: It's a table . . .

Correct! Thanks for all the answers.. this solves the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width for both divs to achieve that..

```
enter code here
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vishal_vash/51w55803/7/)

Answer (score 0):

set width for .first and .second

```
<div class="box first">Username</div>
<div class="box second">This is a short message</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="box first">Username</div>
<div class="box second">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="box first">Username</div>
<div class="box second">Message</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<style>
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.first {
    float: left;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width:20%;
}
.second {
    float: left;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width:60%;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
</style>
```

[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bf78mmr/)

Comment: I don't want to add a specific width, because I'm using bootstrap and it needs to be content depending.

Comment: if you don't want to add width on this classes then use bootstrap [col-lg-etc  ] classes for width. because if you are not set width on this div then your problem no solve

Answer (score 0):

Width required on the div or it will take up `100%` of the available area!

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.first {
    float: left;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.second {
    float: left;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 20px;
  
  /* ADD A WIDTH */
    width: 250px;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<div class="box first">Username</div>
<div class="box second">This is a short message</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="box first">Username</div>
<div class="box second">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="box first">Username</div>
<div class="box second">Message</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated css class, can you please try this one ?

```
.second {
float: left;
color: #0000FF;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0 20px;
width:250px;
}
```